# How to get percentage of matching result in mysql or PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, search

For Example i search some text in particular column like "abcdefgio" and in data base field value is "abcdefghijk..." so i just want to its match 70 - 80% in search string.

Please suggest me some algorithms or library.

Comment: if the string match same as in database then it should be 100% match.

Comment: So you are looking for SQL `LIKE` statement or what?

Comment: Add **%** in query like, `select * from table_name where column_name='%abc'`

Comment: I know % LIKE but using that not get percentage of matching.

Comment: I'd suggest ditching using Mysql the function in the answer below may well work, however it's going to be a real performance killer, instead for your search and use something like Elastic Search which has built in tokenisation which is really what you are looking for, then searching by a percentage match is a simple as setting an INT in the config: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use levenshtein distance:

```
CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein( s1 text, s2 text ) 
  RETURNS INT 
  DETERMINISTIC 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT; 
    DECLARE s1_char CHAR; 
    -- max strlen=255 
    DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(10240); 
    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0; 
    IF s1 = s2 THEN 
      RETURN 0; 
    ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN 
      RETURN s2_len; 
    ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN 
      RETURN s1_len; 
    ELSE 
      WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
        SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1; 
      END WHILE; 
      WHILE i <= s1_len DO 
        SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1; 
        WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
          SET c = c + 1; 
          IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN  
            SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1; 
          END IF; 
          SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost; 
          IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF; 
            SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1; 
            IF c > c_temp THEN  
              SET c = c_temp;  
            END IF; 
            SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1; 
        END WHILE; 
        SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1; 
      END WHILE; 
    END IF; 
    RETURN c; 
  END; 

CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein_ratio( s1 text, s2 text ) 
  RETURNS INT 
  DETERMINISTIC 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, max_len INT; 
    SET s1_len = LENGTH(s1), s2_len = LENGTH(s2); 
    IF s1_len > s2_len THEN  
      SET max_len = s1_len;  
    ELSE  
      SET max_len = s2_len;  
    END IF; 
    RETURN ROUND((1 - LEVENSHTEIN(s1, s2) / max_len) * 100); 
  END;
```

Using:

```
select *
from table1 t1
where levenshtein_ratio(t1.txt1, t1.txt2) > 80
```

Another way, search in MYSQL by LIKE and use function [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) on results

Comment: Thanks @misterX but this function will not return percentage as i mentioned.

Comment: What you mean? SELECT levenshtein_ratio('abcdefgio','abcdefghijk') will return 73. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Hello MisterX,

As you mentioned there are two parameter in function but in second parameter i didn't have value at a time that value is from database so can i specified any field or fields name in second parameter and list of rows with percentage.

Comment: select *
from table1 t1
where levenshtein_ratio(t1.field_from_db, 'search_text') > 80 ?

Comment: But in this case if i swap in text then it will be given wrong percentage

Comment: In function levenshtein_ratio longest string used as 100%, you can remove this lines, or use first string as base RETURN ROUND((1 - LEVENSHTEIN(s1, s2) / s1_len ) * 100);

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This might be late, but it may still be useful.
so, there are two ways of handling this;
1. Levenshtein function for MySQL as stated by @MisterX
2. similar_text function of PHP

Here is how :

**1.Using Levenshtein function for MySQL**

Step 1.

from mysql prompt in the terminal or SQL interface of the phpMyAdmin, create the LEVENSHTEIN function using the following code (simply copy, paste and click on GO button on the interface)

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS LEVENSHTEIN $$
CREATE FUNCTION LEVENSHTEIN(s1 VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8, s2 VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8)
  RETURNS INT
  DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT;
    DECLARE s1_char CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8;
    -- max strlen=255 for this function
    DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256);

    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1),
        s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2),
        cv1 = 0x00,
        j = 1,
        i = 1,
        c = 0;

    IF (s1 = s2) THEN
      RETURN (0);
    ELSEIF (s1_len = 0) THEN
      RETURN (s2_len);
    ELSEIF (s2_len = 0) THEN
      RETURN (s1_len);
    END IF;

    WHILE (j <= s2_len) DO
      SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, CHAR(j)),
          j = j + 1;
    END WHILE;

    WHILE (i <= s1_len) DO
      SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1),
          c = i,
          cv0 = CHAR(i),
          j = 1;

      WHILE (j <= s2_len) DO
        SET c = c + 1,
            cost = IF(s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1), 0, 1);

        SET c_temp = ORD(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)) + cost;
        IF (c > c_temp) THEN
          SET c = c_temp;
        END IF;

        SET c_temp = ORD(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)) + 1;
        IF (c > c_temp) THEN
          SET c = c_temp;
        END IF;

        SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, CHAR(c)),
            j = j + 1;
      END WHILE;

      SET cv1 = cv0,
          i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN (c);
  END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Step 2**
Create levenshtein_ratio function using the following code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein_ratio( s1 text, s2 text ) 
  RETURNS INT 
  DETERMINISTIC 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, max_len INT; 
    SET s1_len = LENGTH(s1), s2_len = LENGTH(s2); 
    IF s1_len > s2_len THEN  
      SET max_len = s1_len;  
    ELSE  
      SET max_len = s2_len;  
    END IF; 
    RETURN ROUND((1 - LEVENSHTEIN(s1, s2) / max_len) * 100); 
  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Step 3:** use the function in your php code like this :

```
 $searchString = $_GET["search"];
    $sql = "select * from table_name
            where levenshtein_ratio($searchString, table_column) >= 70 
                  && levenshtein_ratio($searchString, table_column) <= 80

    " ;
  mysqli_query($conn,$sql)
```

Where $conn references your database connection string .

**DONE**

2. Using similar_text function of PHP.

You query your database like this :

```
$searchString = $_GET["search"];
$sql = "select  * from table_name where table_column like %$searchString%";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$between70and80 = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $string1 = $row["column"];
  $sim = similar_text(strtoupper($search), strtoupper($string1), $perc);
  if($perc>=70 && $perc >=80)
      {
         array_push($between70and80,$string1);
      }

  }

// Now do what you want with $between70and80.
```

Notice the **strtoupper** I used in the similar_text function, I needed both string to be in the same case as this has effect on the percentage match.

Hope this helps someone.